# How to untar large tarball file within disk space constraints?

Tags: unix, gzip, tar

We need to extract five files from a tarball file that contains over 30 files and expands to about 60 GB upon unpacking. Unfortunately, we only have about 20 GB free on the machine. The five files needed only take about 5 GB unpacked.

Is there a way to extract only these five files within our disk space constraints?

Using `tar xvjf <archive> <file>` doesn't seem to work.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you use `tar -xvjf (archive: bzip2-ed tar) (file to unpack)`?

Comment: yes, but the process still took more space than the five files required.

Comment: do one at a time? Good luck.

Comment: I'd try using stdout: `tar -xvjfO <archive> <file1> > file1.result` (capital "o" is for out to stdout).

Comment: @mrówa, how does stdout help?

Comment: What tar are you using?  It works for me with both BSD tar and GNU tar.

Comment: If `tar -xvjf (archive: bzip2-ed tar) (file to unpack)` didn't work, then tar might be unpacking to a temp file just to reach the one file, and that too could very well consume the available disk space.

Comment: @MarkAdler you're saying the amount of disk space during the untarring process never exceeds the size of the files being unpacked? for instance, if we unpacked one 5MB file from a tarball, and only that file, our disk space should only increase by 5MB -- no matter how large the tarball and the other contained files?

Comment: @Crashalot I am able to reproduce Mark Adler's findings. I successfully unpacked a single file from a large tarball, while monitoring the low level file system. The single file unpacked fine, and my system's tar did not create a temp behind the scenes. Your tar may behave differently of course, so it may come down to what OS are you using, and what version of tar is installed?

Comment: @DaveNewman and MarkAdler, we're using tar (GNU tar) 1.23 and CentOS release 6.2 (Final)

Comment: @Crashalot that version of GNU tar should be good, so I'm at a loss for what the problem might be. GNU tar also has a feature to delete elements from a tarball. This would allow you to, in theory, trim the tarball down to the 5 files you need. This feature is described as being slow, and on a tarball that size, probably very slow. It is not something you want to try if you don't have a backup of the tarball.

Comment: thanks @DaveNewman, could you post this as an answer and then we can credit the answer to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU tar has a feature to [delete elements](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#SEC64) from a tarball. This would allow you to, in theory, trim the tarball down to the 5 files you need. This feature is described as being slow, and on a tarball that size, probably very slow. It is not something you want to try if you don't have a backup of the tarball.

Copied from GNU tar's manual is this example:

> To delete all versions of the file ‘blues’ from the archive
>   ‘collection.tar’ in the ‘practice’ directory, make sure you are in
>   that directory, and then,
>
> ```
> $ tar --list --file=collection.tar
> blues
> folk
> jazz
> rock
> $ tar --delete --file=collection.tar blues
> $ tar --list --file=collection.tar
> folk
> jazz
> rock
> ```

Answer (score 0):

On the local server:
nc server 9999 | tar -zxvf -

On the remote server:
nc -l 9999 < yourfile.tar.gz